# Chat App Android using ejabberd 16 and XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

Can anybody tell me in detail what is the exact use of following methods?

```
   XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(false);
   XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(false);
   XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(false);
```

I want user to be gone offline when internet connection is lost.

I have implemented mod_ping on server as below

```
 [{send_pings, true}, {ping_interval, 2},
 {ping_ack_timeout, 2},
 {timeout_action, kill}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(false);
// Set if Stream Management should be used by default for new connections.

  XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(false);

// Set if Stream Management resumption should be used by default for new connections.

   XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumption(false);

// Set if Stream Management resumption should be used if supported by the server.
```

for more detail take a look [here](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/)